# DynamoDB can't convert objec to list

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

I am having an odd issue with my code whereby when I am trying to fetch data from my DyanmoDB it throws an error each time it tries to convert the following POCO object that I can see in my Dynamo

Error in question:

```
Error converting value "[{"Id":"131b3fe5-01d2-4ac7-9541-f0e54965f867","FileName":"Healthier Living_October2019.pdf","DisplayName":"Healthier Living","AssociatedText":null}]" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Entities.Domain.Aggregates.Resources.ResourceDocument]'. Path '[0].Documents', line 1, position 411.
```

How object looks in DB:

```
[{"Id":"131b3fe5-01d2-4ac7-9541-f0e54965f867","FileName":"Healthier Living_October2019.pdf","DisplayName":"Healthier Living","AssociatedText":null}]
```

It is clearly a List object given the [], thus it shouldn't have any issues with the following property definition I have:

```
[DynamoDBProperty(Converter = typeof(ResourceDocumentsConverter))]
public List<ResourceDocument> Documents { get; set; }
```

I've also tried adding a converter to see if I can manually massage the data, however, it is not even hitting the convert in the first place at all.

```
public class ResourceDocumentsConverter : IPropertyConverter
    {
        public object FromEntry(DynamoDBEntry entry)
        {
            try
            {
                var primitive = entry as DynamoDBList;
                if (primitive == null) return null;

                var results = primitive.AsString();
                var final = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ResourceDocument>>(results);

                return final;
            }
            catch
            {
                return new List<ResourceDocument>();
            }

        }

        public DynamoDBEntry ToEntry(object value)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return null;

            return new Primitive(value.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Where exactly am I going awry with this? As I understand it, Dynamo shouldn't have any issues with storing complex objects as it would instead just write them as JSON blobs.